# Is it possible to command 'dmsetup' in Android devices?

Tags: android, adb, android-source, device-mapper

I would like to create new device mapper devices in Android.

As I know Android uses 'dm-crypt' which is part of the 'device mapper'. But, I can't use command `dmsetup` by `adb shell` in  the android deivce. Is it possible to command `dmsetup` in Android devices? How can I use 'dmsetup' in Android? Is there way to make new device mapper device?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I also have some issues with it (no way to find how I can get the "dm-default-key" module on my kernel), but a different one. As far as I can understand, the tool under Android is named "dmctl" and not "dmsetup".

Try "dmctl help" using adb. To list targets, "dmctl list targets -v", to list devices, "dmctl list devices -v", and so on.